# ' character in string parameter of Odata Url

Tags: wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

Hmmm this seems silly, so I feel silly. I have a custom operation on an Odata service which has a string parameter. It works fine when the string contains no special characters, but as soon as I include the ['] character I get:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\r\n<error xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata\">\r\n  <code></code>\r\n  <message xml:lang=\"en-US\">Bad Request - Error in query syntax.</message>\r\n</error>
```

I am invoking the service with the following code:

```
new DataServiceContext(new Uri(svcUri)).Execute<string>(new Uri(relativeOperationUrl, UriKind.Relative));
```

I've tried encoding like this [& apos;] (xml encoding) and like this [%27] (url encoding) and the things is still blowing up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape a single quote to be used in an OData query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979367/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-to-be-used-in-an-odata-query)

Comment: Yeah sorry didn't find that question, it seems to be the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `''` (like escaping it for SQL); see [How to escape a single quote to be used in an OData query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979367/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-to-be-used-in-an-odata-query).