# Azure DevOps UserEntitlements REST API with filter fails for single quoted string value

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the userentitlement REST API in Azure DevOps and when using the filter parameter with a single quoted string as a value , I get the error .
Here is my request

```
https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{Myorganization}/_apis/userentitlements?$filter=name+eq+'Gary D'Jessi'&api-version=5.1-preview.3
```

This is the response I get

```
{
"$id": "1",
"innerException": null,
"message": "Invalid filter: \"name eq 'Gary D'Jessi'\"",
"typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Exceptions.InvalidQueryStringException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi",
"typeKey": "InvalidQueryStringException",
"errorCode": 0,
"eventId": 3000
```

}

I tried using the solution with https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483742/7841330 but did not help.

Comment: As you said, you tried a solution from other SO question. Can you provide your request with `''` and the response, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to escape is to place two single quotes into the string instead one.

For example  **name+eq+'Gary D''Jessi'**

I tested in postman and it worked fine.
[image: RESULT]

Hope it can help you.